# How do I parse an array of array JSON in Jackson JSON parser

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring

I have a api that spits out the following JSON:

```
{
    "monitors": [
        [
            "/Common/http-cc-ping-any"
        ]
    ],
    "is_alive":true
}
```

I'm trying to use spring and Jackson JSON Parser to map the JSON to a POJO

The POJO is defined as :

```
public class MonitorsList {

    @JsonProperty("monitors")
    private List<Monitors> monitors;

    public void setMonitors(List<Monitors> monitors) {
        this.monitors = monitors;
    }

    public List<Monitors> getMonitors() {
        return this.monitors;
    }

    private boolean is_alive;

    public void setIsAlive(boolean is_alive) {
        this.is_alive= is_alive;
    }

    public boolean getIsAlive() {
        return this.is_alive;
    }
}
```

and my Monitor POJO is :

```
@JsonAutoDetect
public class Monitors {
     private ArrayList<String> monitors;

     public ArrayList<String> getMonitors() {
            return this.monitors;
        }

        public void setMonitors(ArrayList<String> monitors) {
            this.monitors = monitors;
        }
}
```

I'm using a RestTemplate to retrieve the JSON data, but I get the following error:

> Error: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of hello.Monitors out of START_ARRAY token
>    at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2a2c13a8; line: 1, column: 14] (through reference chain: hello.MonitorsList ["monitors"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of hello.Monitors out of START_ARRAY token
>    at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2a2c13a8; line: 1, column: 14] (through reference chain: hello.MonitorsList ["monitors"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have a JSON array of JSON arrays of JSON strings. How do you expect that to map to a `List<Monitor>`?

Comment: I did try using ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> content in Greeting.java, but still didn't work

Comment: Do you mean in `MonitorsList`?

Comment: No. In my Monitor.java file, I tried ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> monitors ( earlier it was named as content)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I figured out what you meant earlier! Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `@SotiriosDelimanolis` and a little reading up, I was able to figure out what I was doing wrong.

So, JacksonJSON Parser maps a

```
{
    "monitors": [
        [
            "/Common/http-cc-ping-any"
        ]
    ],
    "is_alive":true
}
```

as the following POJO:

```
public class MonitorsList {

    @JsonProperty("monitors")
    private List<Monitors> monitors;

    public void setMonitors(List<Monitors> monitors) {
        this.monitors = monitors;
    }

    public List<Monitors> getMonitors() {
        return this.monitors;
    }

    @JsonProperty("is_alive")
    private boolean is_alive;

    public void setIsAlive(boolean is_alive) {
        this.is_alive= is_alive;
    }

    public boolean getIsAlive() {
        return this.is_alive;
    }
}
```

And Monitor POJO as :

```
@JsonAutoDetect
public class Monitors extends ArrayList<String> {
}
```

***Note*** that is_alive does not map to `setIsAlive`, so providing the annotation `@JsonProperty("is_alive")` to either the field `is_alive` or the method `setIsAlive` will work!

Comment: Note that I wouldn't recommend creating a subclass of `ArrayList`. Composition is generally better. Look into `@JsonCreator`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.